# Battle of Browser Compatibility Layout Centering: IE and Mozilla

Tags: css

So based on previous help, putting `margin: 0 auto` on the container and removing ALL margin properties on the **content box** worked perfectly in Mozilla Firefox but **Internet Explorer** was a disaster.

It got so bad that the website was all scrambled up. I'd like to try this again.

How can I center the content box on both Internet Explorer and Mozilla?

**The CSS Code**: [style_sample.css](http://avisuals.web.fc2.com/style_sample.css)

**Webpage**: [http://avisuals.web.fc2.com/sample.html](http://avisuals.web.fc2.com/sample.html#)

Comment: No. Sorry I mean it doesn't work fine when I remove the margin-left, margin-right, margin-top to position places in the CSS style sheet. If I only have 960 width and margin: 0 auto as the container it won't work in Internet Explorer, only in Mozilla.

Comment: Can be closed based on the official close reason: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page has no `doctype` declaration, e.g.:

```
<!doctype html>    
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
```

Hence, the browser is being thrown into Internet 5.5/Netscape/1998 compatibility/quirks mode:

[image]

If you add the `<!doctype html>` declaration to throw it into *standards mode* (which i can simulate by changing the browser into *standards mode*):

[image]

the page then renders fine for me.

---

**Internet Explorer (Quirks mode)**:
[image]

**Internet Explorer**:
[image]

**Chrome**:
[image]

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH IAN! Perfect! It worked! I learned a lot. I did it completely backwards and forgot to put it in when using the HTML Editor. This is a lesson I won't forget!